# Delay in while loop and its precision

Tags: c#

I am writing C# code to make data acquire system from FPGA with USB communication and not that familiar with C#.
The system received data continuously at regular intervals through USB.
Data is continuously received only when `DOPPLER_NUM = 1`, and `while (DOPPLER_NUM == 1)` is that process.
And there are two problems in operation.

1. When I operate code without `Delay(1)` in while loop, the program is completely stopped and none of the buttons in the program works.
2. I used `Delay` function to solve the problem, and it works.
   But, the delay I want is 1ms and it actually varies from 1-15ms when I measured it with Stopwatch function.

```
public void Delay(int MS)
{
    DateTime ThisMoment = DateTime.Now;
    TimeSpan Duration = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, MS);
    DateTime AfterWards = DateTime.Now.Add(Duration);

    while (AfterWards >= ThisMoment)
    {
         System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();
         ThisMoment = DateTime.Now;
    }
    return;
}
```

```
int DOPPLER_NUM = 0;

private void Doppler_Start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
     int transmit_mode = 1; 

     if (DOPPLER_NUM == 0)
     {
          DOPPLER_NUM = 1;
          transmit_mode = 1;
     }
     else
     {
          DOPPLER_NUM = 0;
          transmit_mode = 0;
          cnt4GS = 0;
     }

     CyBulkEndPoint Inednpt1;
     Inednpt1 = MyDevice.EndPointOf(0x86) as CyBulkEndPoint;

     int bytes1 = Convert.ToInt32(256);
     int bytes2 = bytes1 * 2;

     bool bXferCompleted = false;

     bool IsPkt = false;

     byte[] buffer4GS = new byte[400 * 256];

     byte[] buffer1 = new byte[bytes2];
     byte[] Data_buf = new byte[bytes1];

     while (DOPPLER_NUM == 1)
     {
          Stopwatch clk1 = new Stopwatch();
          clk1.Start();

          Delay(1);
  
          clk1.Stop();
          opertime.Text = (clk1.ElapsedTicks * 100 / 1000).ToString() + " us";                    

          if (MyDevice != null)
          {
               if (Inednpt1 != null)
               {                           
                   bXferCompleted = Inednpt1.XferData(ref buffer1, ref bytes2, IsPkt); // Data receiving from USB
                                                           
                   Data_buf = Doppler_Processing(buffer1, bytes2);
             
                   if (cnt4GS >= 0 && cnt4GS <= 399)
                   {
                         Buffer.BlockCopy(Data_buf, 0, buffer4GS, cnt4GS * 256, 256);
                         cnt4GS++;
                    }
                    else if (cnt4GS >= 400)
                    {
                         Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer4GS, 256, buffer4GS, 0, 102144);
                         Buffer.BlockCopy(Data_buf, 0, buffer4GS, 102144, 256);
                     }

                     Grayscale(buffer4GS);                               
                }                           
           }
           else if (MyDevice == null)
           {
               MessageBox.Show("ERROR. NODEVICE.", "Error Message");
               break;
           }
       }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Delay` method gives the UI thread to handle events, by calling `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();`

If you have an intensive operation bound to your UI thread (which explains the behaviour) you'll end up with a blocked UI. The usage of `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();` can resolve this, but it would be better to just execute your `DOPPLER_NUM` loop in another thread - not bothering the UI thread with it and keeping your program responsive.

Alternatively, you can just call `System.Windows.Forms.Application.DoEvents();` from your loop itself and it would work just as good, maybe increasing performance a bit.

Also:

Alternatives like `Task.Delay` and `Thread.Sleep` will not have a better accuracy as about 5ms. This is by design - because measuring the exact time will cost CPU power, same as the stopwatch does.

Comment: Hi @Stefan
Thank you for your reply. I am just a beginner in C# and want to clarify what you are talking about. I understand that "my code does not use multiple threads and only use UI thread, so if `DOPPLER_NUM` loop is not prcoess as an independent thread, an error occurs". Is it right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.